# Как вывести значение поля properties в админку?

Tags: javascript, modx, extjs

Добрый день!
Пытаюсь добавить кастомное поле в админку и вывести туда значение сохраненное в БД в поле 'properties'.
В файл assets\components\tickets\js\mgr\comment\comment.window.js добавил:

```
{
 xtype: 'textfield',
 fieldLabel: 'Телефон',
 name: 'properties',
 anchor: '99%',
}
```

В админке отобразилось добавляемое поле, но поле 'properties' содержит json массив ({«phone»:«7(111)111-11-11»,«requiredFields»:«name,email»}) и соответственно в админке я получаю '[object Object]'.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как получить и вывести в админку только значение по ключу 'phone'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря доброму человеку по имени Марат Марабар ( [marabar.ru](https://marabar.ru/), [Github](https://github.com/Marabar) ), который не остался равнодушен к данному вопросу, проблема была разрешена. В файл assets\components\tickets\js\mgr\comment\comment.window.js необходимо добавить следующий код, вместо указанного в вопросе:

```
{
  xtype: 'displayfield',
  fieldLabel: 'Телефон',
  html: config.record.properties.phone,
  anchor: '99%',
}
```

Comment: Добрый день. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/879880/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%B4-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5-properties-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0

Посмотрите пожалуйста !

Answer (score 0):

Этот код будет работать только когда phone будет первым объектом в БД. Если объект второй или третий то код не сработает.
В файле /assets/components/tickets/js/mgr/comment/comment.window.js добавляете дополнительное поле

`, {
xtype: 'displayfield',
fieldLabel: 'Комментарий',
html: config.record.properties['comment-plus'],
anchor: '99%',
}`

config.record.properties['comment-plus'] вместо comment-plus любой объект из поля properties в БД.