# Как вывести в админке тикетах (данные с бд таблицы в массиве properties одно значение number)?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, modx

```
Modx plugin tickets
    <?php

if (empty($_REQUEST['action'])) {
    die('Access denied');
}
else {
    $action = $_REQUEST['action'];
}

define('MODX_API_MODE', true);
define('MSEARCH2_AJAX', true);
require_once dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))).'/index.php';

$modx->getService('error','error.modError');
$modx->getRequest();
$modx->setLogLevel(modX::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR);
$modx->setLogTarget('FILE');
$modx->error->message = null;

// Get properties
$properties = array();
/* @var TicketThread $thread */
if (!empty($_REQUEST['thread']) && $thread = $modx->getObject('TicketThread', array('name' => $_REQUEST['thread']))) {
    $properties = $thread->get('properties');
}
elseif (!empty($_REQUEST['form_key']) && isset($_SESSION['TicketForm'][$_REQUEST['form_key']])) {
    $properties = $_SESSION['TicketForm'][$_REQUEST['form_key']];
}
elseif (!empty($_SESSION['TicketForm'])) {
    $properties = $_SESSION['TicketForm'];
}

// Switch context
$context = 'web';
if (!empty($thread) && $thread->resource && $resource = $thread->getOne('Resource')) {
    $context = $resource->get('context_key');
}
elseif (!empty($_REQUEST['parent']) && $resource = $modx->getObject('modResource', $_REQUEST['parent'])) {
    $context = $resource->get('context_key');
}
elseif (!empty($_REQUEST['ctx']) && $modx->getCount('modContext', $_REQUEST['ctx'])) {
    $context = $_REQUEST['ctx'];
}
if ($context != 'web') {
    $modx->switchContext($context);
}

/* @var Tickets $Tickets */
define('MODX_ACTION_MODE', true);
$Tickets = $modx->getService('tickets','Tickets',$modx->getOption('tickets.core_path',null,$modx->getOption('core_path').'components/tickets/').'model/tickets/', $properties);
if ($modx->error->hasError() || !($Tickets instanceof Tickets)) {
    die('Error');
}

switch ($action) {
    case 'comment/preview': $response = $Tickets->previewComment($_POST); break;
    case 'comment/save': $response = $Tickets->saveComment($_POST); break;
    case 'comment/get': $response = $Tickets->getComment($_POST['id']); break;
    case 'comment/getlist': $response = $Tickets->getNewComments($_POST['thread']); break;
    case 'comment/subscribe': $response = $Tickets->subscribeThread($_POST['thread']); break;
    case 'comment/vote': $response = $Tickets->voteComment($_POST['id'], $_POST['value']); break;
    case 'comment/star': $response = $Tickets->starComment($_POST['id']); break;

    case 'ticket/draft':
    case 'ticket/publish':
    case 'ticket/update':
    case 'ticket/save': $response = $Tickets->saveTicket($_POST); break;
    case 'ticket/preview': $response = $Tickets->previewTicket($_POST); break;
    case 'ticket/vote': $response = $Tickets->voteTicket($_POST['id'], $_POST['value']); break;
    case 'ticket/star': $response = $Tickets->starTicket($_POST['id']); break;

    case 'section/subscribe': $response = $Tickets->subscribeSection($_POST['section']); break;

    case 'ticket/file/upload': $response = $Tickets->fileUpload($_POST, 'Ticket'); break;
    case 'ticket/file/delete': $response = $Tickets->fileDelete($_POST['id']); break;
    default:
        $message = $_REQUEST['action'] != $action ? 'tickets_err_register_globals' : 'tickets_err_unknown';
        $response = $modx->toJSON(array('success' => false, 'message' => $modx->lexicon($message)));
}

if (is_array($response)) {
    $response = $modx->toJSON($response);
}

@session_write_close();
exit($response);ъ
```

Вот Php код и снизу js

```
    Tickets.grid.Comments = function(config) {
    var 
    config = config || {};

    Ext.applyIf(config,{
        url: Tickets.config.connector_url,
        baseParams: {
            action: 'mgr/comment/getlist',
            section: config.section,
            parents: config.parents,
            threads: config.threads,
        },
        fields: this.getFields(config),
        columns: this.getColumns(config),
        tbar: this.getTopBar(config),
        listeners: this.getListeners(config),
        sm: new Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel(),
        autoHeight: true,
        paging: true,
        remoteSort: true,
        viewConfig: {
            forceFit: true,
            enableRowBody: true,
            showPreview: true,
            getRowClass: function(rec, ri, p) {
                var cls = [];
                if (!rec.data.published) {
                    cls.push('tickets-row-unpublished');
                }
                if (rec.data.deleted) {
                    cls.push('tickets-row-deleted');
                }
                return cls.join(' ');
            },
        },
        stateful: true,
        stateId: 'tickets-comments-state',
    });
    Tickets.grid.Comments.superclass.constructor.call(this,config);
    this.getStore().sortInfo = {
        field: 'createdon',
        direction: 'DESC'
    };
};
Ext.extend(Tickets.grid.Comments,MODx.grid.Grid,{

    getFields: function(config) {
        return [
            'id', 'properties', 'text', 'name', 'parent', 'email', 'ip', 'thread_name',
            'createdby', 'createdon', 'editedon', 'editedby', 'deletedon', 'deletedby',
            'published', 'deleted', 'resource', 'pagetitle', 'preview_url', 'actions',
        ];

    },
    getColumns: function(config) {
        return [{
            header: _('id'),
            dataIndex: 'id',
            width: 25,
            sortable: true,
        },{
            header: _('ticket_comment_text'),
            dataIndex: 'text',
            width: 75,
            sortable: true
        },{
            header: _('ticket_comment_name'),
            dataIndex: 'name',
            sortable: true,
            width: 50,
            renderer: function(value, metaData, record) {
                return Tickets.utils.userLink(value, record['data']['createdby'])
            },
        },{
            header: _('ticket_comment_createdon'),
            dataIndex: 'createdon',
            width: 50,
            sortable: true,
            renderer: Tickets.utils.formatDate
        },{
            header: _('ticket'),
            dataIndex: 'pagetitle',
            width: 75,
            sortable: true,
            renderer: function(value, metaData, record) {
                return Tickets.utils.ticketLink(value, record['data']['resource'], true)
            },
            hidden: config.parents || config.threads ? 1 : 0
        },{
            header: ("ИИН"),
            dataIndex: 'properties.number',
            width: 40,
            sortable: true
        },{
            header: ("Адрес"),
            dataIndex: 'adress',
            width: 40,
            sortable: true
        },{
            header: _('ticket_comment_thread'),
            dataIndex: 'thread_name',
            width: 40,
            sortable: true,
            hidden: config.threads != '' && config.threads != 0,
        },{
            header: _('ticket_actions'),
            dataIndex: 'actions',
            renderer: Tickets.utils.renderActions,
            sortable: false,
            width: 75,
            id: 'actions'
        }];
    },

    getTopBar: function(config) {
        return ['->', {
            xtype: 'tickets-field-search',
            width: 250,
            listeners: {
                search: {fn: function(field) {
                    this._doSearch(field);
                }, scope: this},
                clear: {fn: function(field) {
                    field.setValue('');
                    this._clearSearch();
                }, scope: this},
            }
        }];
    },

    getListeners: function(config) {
        return {
            rowDblClick: function(grid, rowIndex, e) {
                var row = grid.store.getAt(rowIndex);
                this.editComment(grid, e, row);
            }
        };
    },

    getMenu: function (grid, rowIndex) {
        var ids = this._getSelectedIds();

        var row = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
        var menu = Tickets.utils.getMenu(row.data['actions'], this, ids);

        this.addContextMenuItem(menu);
    },

    onClick: function (e) {
        var elem = e.getTarget();
        if (elem.nodeName == 'BUTTON') {
            var row = this.getSelectionModel().getSelected();
            if (typeof(row) != 'undefined') {
                var action = elem.getAttribute('action');
                if (action == 'showMenu') {
                    var ri = this.getStore().find('id', row.id);
                    return this._showMenu(this, ri, e);
                }
                else if (typeof this[action] === 'function') {
                    this.menu.record = row.data;
                    return this[action](this, e);
                }
            }
        }
        return this.processEvent('click', e);
    },

    _doSearch: function (tf) {
        this.getStore().baseParams.query = tf.getValue();
        this.getBottomToolbar().changePage(1);
    },

    _clearSearch: function() {
        this.getStore().baseParams.query = '';
        this.getBottomToolbar().changePage(1);
    },

    editComment: function(btn, e, row) {
        var record = typeof(row) != 'undefined'
            ? row.data
            : this.menu.record;

        MODx.Ajax.request({
            url: Tickets.config.connector_url,
            params: {
                action: 'mgr/comment/get',
                id: record.id,
            },
            listeners: {
                success: {fn:function(r) {
                    var record = r.object;
                    var w = MODx.load({
                        xtype: 'tickets-window-comment-update',
                        record: record,
                        listeners: {
                            success: {
                                fn: this.refresh,
                                scope: this
                            },
                        },
                    });
                    w.fp.getForm().reset();
                    w.fp.getForm().setValues(record);
                    w.show(e.target);
                },scope:this}
            }
        });
    },

    viewComment: function(btn,e) {
        window.open(this.menu.record['preview_url'] + '#comment-' + this.menu.record['id']);
        return false;
    },

    commentAction: function(method) {
        var ids = this._getSelectedIds();
        if (!ids.length) {
            return false;
        }
        MODx.Ajax.request({
            url: Tickets.config.connector_url,
            params: {
                action: 'mgr/comment/multiple',
                method: method,
                ids: Ext.util.JSON.encode(ids),
            },
            listeners: {
                success: {
                    fn: function () {
                        this.refresh();
                    }, scope: this
                },
                failure: {
                    fn: function (response) {
                        MODx.msg.alert(_('error'), response.message);
                    }, scope: this
                },
            }
        })
    },

    publishComment: function(btn,e) {
        this.commentAction('publish');
    },

    unpublishComment: function(btn,e) {
        this.commentAction('unpublish');
    },

    deleteComment: function(btn,e) {
        this.commentAction('delete');
    },

    undeleteComment: function(btn,e) {
        this.commentAction('undelete');
    },

    removeComment: function() {
        Ext.MessageBox.confirm(
            _('ticket_comment_remove'),
            _('ticket_comment_remove_confirm'),
            function(val) {
                if (val == 'yes') {
                    this.commentAction('remove');
                }
            },
            this
        );
    },

    _getSelectedIds: function() {
        var ids = [];
        var selected = this.getSelectionModel().getSelections();

        for (var i in selected) {
            if (!selected.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                continue;
            }
            ids.push(selected[i]['id']);
        }

        return ids;
    },

    // Grid onremove fix
    remove: function() {},

});
Ext.reg('tickets-grid-comments',Tickets.grid.Comments);
```

Получается все сделал осталось только в админке что бы в списке отоброжение появилось 
https://github.com/bezumkin/Tickets/blob/master/assets/components/tickets/js/mgr/comment/comments.grid.js
как можете видеть со строки 56 начинается отображение в админке в табличном виде данных мне бы добавить туда из базы данных таблицы и внутри таблицы массив properties[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
{
        header: ("ИИН"),
        dataIndex: 'properties',
        width: 40,
        sortable: true,
        renderer: function(value, metaData, record) {
            return Tickets.utils.ticketLink(value['number'], record['data']['resource'], true)
        }
    }
```

Вот еще пытаюсь может кому это поможет? хотя не сработало (

Вот еще get list может тут не хватает чего что бы properties выводился?

```
    <?php

class TicketCommentsGetListProcessor extends modObjectGetListProcessor
{
    public $objectType = 'TicketComment';
    public $classKey = 'TicketComment';
    public $languageTopics = array('tickets:default');
    public $defaultSortField = 'createdon';
    public $defaultSortDirection = 'DESC';


    /**
     * @param xPDOQuery $c
     *
     * @return xPDOQuery
     */
    public function prepareQueryBeforeCount(xPDOQuery $c)
    {
        /* Get all comments by section */
        if ($section = (int)$this->getProperty('section')) {
            if ($section = $this->modx->getObject('modResource', $section)) {
                $parents = $this->modx->getChildIds($section->get('id'), 1,
                    array('context' => $section->get('context_key')));
                if (empty($parents)) {
                    $parents = array('0');
                }
                $c->where(array('Thread.resource:IN' => $parents));
            }
        } /* OR get all comments by threads list */
        elseif ($threads = $this->getProperty('threads')) {
            if (!is_array($threads)) {
                $threads = explode(',', $threads);
            }
            if (!empty($threads)) {
                $c->where(array('TicketComment.thread:IN' => $threads));
            }
        } /* OR get all comments by tickets list */
        elseif ($parents = $this->getProperty('parents')) {
            if (!is_array($parents)) {
                $parents = explode(',', $parents);
            }
            if (!empty($parents)) {
                $c->where(array('Thread.resource:IN' => $parents));
            }
        } /* OR get all comments */
        else {
            //$c->where(array('Thread.resource:!=' => 0));
        }

        if ($query = $this->getProperty('query', null)) {
            $query = trim($query);
            if (is_numeric($query)) {
                $c->where(array(
                    'TicketComment.id:=' => $query,
                    'OR:TicketComment.parent:=' => $query,
                ));

            } else {
                $c->where(array(
                    'TicketComment.text:LIKE' => '%' . $query . '%',
                    'OR:TicketComment.name:LIKE' => '%' . $query . '%',
                    'OR:TicketComment.email:LIKE' => '%' . $query . '%',
                ));
            }
        }

        $c->leftJoin('TicketThread', 'Thread');
        $c->leftJoin('modUser', 'User');
        $c->leftJoin('modUserProfile', 'UserProfile');
        $c->leftJoin('modResource', 'Resource', 'Thread.resource = Resource.id');
        $c->select($this->modx->getSelectColumns('TicketComment', 'TicketComment'));
        $c->select(array(
            'Thread.resource',
            'Thread.properties',
            'thread_name' => 'Thread.name',
            'User.username',
            'UserProfile.fullname',
            'Resource.pagetitle',
            'Resource.context_key',
        ));
        $c->groupby('TicketComment.id');

        return $c;
    }


    /**
     * @param xPDOObject $object
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareRow(xPDOObject $object)
    {
        $array = parent::prepareRow($object);

        $array['text'] = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($array['text'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
        if (!empty($array['fullname'])) {
            $array['name'] = $array['fullname'];
        } elseif (!empty($array['username'])) {
            $array['name'] = $array['username'];
        }
        if (!empty($array['properties']['threadUrl'])) {
            $array['preview_url'] = $array['properties']['threadUrl'];
        } elseif (!empty($array['resource'])) {
            $this->modx->getContext($array['context_key']);
            $array['preview_url'] = $this->modx->makeUrl($array['resource'], $array['context_key']);
        }
        unset($array['properties']);

        $array['actions'] = array();

        // Edit
        $array['actions'][] = array(
            'cls' => '',
            'icon' => 'icon icon-edit',
            'title' => $this->modx->lexicon('tickets_action_edit'),
            'action' => 'editComment',
            'button' => empty($array['deleted']) || !empty($array['published']),
            'menu' => true,
        );

        // View
        if (!empty($array['preview_url']) && !empty($array['published']) && empty($array['deleted'])) {
            $array['actions'][] = array(
                'cls' => '',
                'icon' => 'icon icon-eye',
                'title' => $this->modx->lexicon('tickets_action_view'),
                'action' => 'viewComment',
                'button' => true,
                'menu' => true,
            );
        }

        // Publish
        if (!$array['published']) {
            $array['actions'][] = array(
                'cls' => '',
                'icon' => 'icon icon-power-off action-green',
                'title' => $this->modx->lexicon('tickets_action_publish'),
                'multiple' => $this->modx->lexicon('tickets_action_publish'),
                'action' => 'publishComment',
                'button' => true,
                'menu' => true,
            );
        } else {
            $array['actions'][] = array(
                'cls' => '',
                'icon' => 'icon icon-power-off action-gray',
                'title' => $this->modx->lexicon('tickets_action_unpublish'),
                'multiple' => $this->modx->lexicon('tickets_action_unpublish'),
                'action' => 'unpublishComment',
                'button' => false,
                'menu' => true,
            );
        }

        // Delete
        if (!$array['deleted']) {
            $array['actions'][] = array(
                'cls' => '',
                'icon' => 'icon icon-trash-o action-yellow',
                'title' => $this->modx->lexicon('tickets_action_delete'),
                'multiple' => $this->modx->lexicon('tickets_action_delete'),
                'action' => 'deleteComment',
                'button' => false,
                'menu' => true,
            );
        } else {
            $array['actions'][] = array(
                'cls' => '',
                'icon' => 'icon icon-undo action-green',
                'title' => $this->modx->lexicon('tickets_action_undelete'),
                'multiple' => $this->modx->lexicon('tickets_action_undelete'),
                'action' => 'undeleteComment',
                'button' => true,
                'menu' => true,
            );
        }

        $array['actions'][] = array(
            'cls' => '',
            'icon' => 'icon icon-trash-o action-red',
            'title' => $this->modx->lexicon('tickets_action_remove'),
            'multiple' => $this->modx->lexicon('tickets_action_remove'),
            'action' => 'removeComment',
            'button' => false,
            'menu' => true,
        );

        // Menu
        $array['actions'][] = array(
            'cls' => '',
            'icon' => 'icon icon-cog actions-menu',
            'menu' => false,
            'button' => true,
            'action' => 'showMenu',
            'type' => 'menu',
        );

        return $array;
    }

}

return 'TicketCommentsGetListProcessor';
```

Comment: А вам вот это случаем не поможет? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/702532/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-properties-%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83?rq=1
Я не силен в modx

Comment: К сожалению не поможет с моей проблемой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не сможете получит свойства из таблицы комментариев - они перезаписываются свойствами из таблицы веток комментариев.
А в методе **prepareRow** уничтожаются

```
unset($array['properties']);
```

Если править исходники, можно сделать следующее;
js, **getFields**:

```
getFields: function(config) {
    return [
        'id', 'inn_number', 'text', 'name', 'parent', 'email', 'ip', 'thread_name',
        'createdby', 'createdon', 'editedon', 'editedby', 'deletedon', 'deletedby',
        'published', 'deleted', 'resource', 'pagetitle', 'preview_url', 'actions',
    ];

},
```

**getColumns**

```
{
        header: 'Properties',
        dataIndex: 'inn_number',
        width: 100,
        sortable: true,
        renderer: function (v, m, r) { return v;  }
    }
```

Processor **getlist.class.php**, метод **prepareQueryBeforeCount** добавьте **'TicketComment.properties'**

```
$c->select(array(
        'Thread.resource',
        'Thread.properties',
        'thread_name' => 'Thread.name',
        'User.username',
        'UserProfile.fullname',
        'Resource.pagetitle',
        'Resource.context_key',
        'TicketComment.properties',
    ));
```

в методе **prepareRow** добавьте перед unset()

```
$array['inn_number'] = $array['properties']['number'];
unset($array['properties']);
```

Должно работать.
Но учтите, что при обновлении компонента эти изменения перезапишутся. А вообще на пулреквест тянет.

Comment: Огромное спасибо вам!

Comment: Добрый день а можно у вас заказать помощь ? у меня ответить на комменты перестало работать в тикетах(

Comment: Напишите мне на marat@marabar.ru